# How to ignore return result

Tags: livescript

for example

```
child.stdout.on \data (buffer) -> 
   result.stdout += buffer
```

-->

```
child.stdout.on('data', function(buffer){
  return result.stdout += buffer;
});
```

and I need it without return. In F# I can add `|> ignore` how can I handle it in livescript?

Comment: i'm curious why you need to have no return clause,as you can just ignore the result of the function call ?

Comment: @niahoo If the last expression is a loop, it will create an array with all the elements and return it. This may be expensive. With `!->` it won’t create the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prepend an `!` to the definition of the function:

```
!(buffer) -> result.stdout += buffer
```

Alternatively, return `void`

```
child.stdout.on \data (buffer) -> 
   result.stdout += buffer
   void
```

In JavaScript, when you return undefined (void), it is the same as not returning anything.

Comment: You can just put `return` instead of `void`. I'm not sure what's best practice, but `return` lets you return nothing in the middle of a function: `return if something`